# How to avoid the error when I try to update the lucene index at the same time when visitor are visiting the web?

Tags: solr, lucene

How to avoid the error when I try to update the  lucene  index  at the same time when visitor are visiting the web? Now I can only update the index at midnight because there are a few visitors visiting the web.

Comment: please provide an example of error. By design lucene supports concurrent updates/search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, by "updating the index" you mean to empty the index and the fill it with new data, a full refeed? You can avoid having an empty index with by using a [timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061059/know-indexing-time-for-a-document-in-solr) field and with the following method:

1. Save the time the update starts
2. Queue `DELETE` command for all documents older than startdate
3. Queue the adding of all the new documents
4. Execute `COMMIT`

This way, the old documents are available until the very last moment and afterwards, all new docs are already there. Be careful not to use autoCommit and to disable synchronisation in slave nodes for the time of refeeding or you may end up with ugly results.